# Does Homebrew get removed after upgrading Mac OS?

Tags: macos, homebrew, mojave

I recently upgraded my Mac from 10.13 to 10.14 and I can't seem to find my Homebrew. /usr/local is practically empty; just MySQL remains. Does brew get removed after an OS upgrade? Should I install it from scratch? What about the packages I installed using homebrew on the older version?

Comment: It shouldn't, and it never happened to me.

Comment: First time for me too. All my Homebrew packages have vanished and I don't have a clue how/why. I had installed Mongo and MySQL using brew. They're gone too. Absolutely no traces left.

Answer (score 1):

You should run `brew update` and see what happens. If Homebrew refuses to run, reinstall it using the command at https://brew.sh.

You should then run `brew upgrade` to make sure you're running the latest packages. If `brew list` shows no packages, then it looks like you'll have to re-install these packages.

Comment: Tried. "brew update" threw a "command not found" error. I've reinstalled Homebrew and ended up reinstalling some other packages. What I'm not able to understand is how/why brew got removed on an OS upgrade when all my other installations and files are fine... :(

Comment: @PrateekDewan I do not know specifically why, but some parts of the system are reset by the system update

Comment: running "brew update" just now seemingly uninstalled/deleted it from my system (macOS 10.13.6) which i haven't upgraded in a while. just completely vanished after a few lines of output, nothing indicating that it'd be nuking itself. guess i'll re-install from scratch.